# Looping array data within blade

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I make some API calls and fill up an array.  I have identified three different ways an array element might come

```
array:9 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "jobData" => array:5 [▶]
    "clientData" => array:3 [▶]
  ]
  5 => array:3 [▼
    "jobData" => array:5 [▶]
    "clientData" => array:3 [▶]
    "customData" => array:1 [▼
      "Type of work" => array:1 [▼
        "Type of work" => "Something"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  8 => array:3 [▼
    "jobData" => array:5 [▶]
    "clientData" => array:3 [▶]
    "customData" => array:2 [▼
      "Month" => array:1 [▼
        "Month" => "Aug 16"
      ]
      "Type of work" => array:1 [▼
        "Type of work" => "Something"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

So Element 0 only has jobData and clientData.  Element 5 has these two plus a cusomtData for Type of Work.  Element 8 has everything including customData
for Type of Work and Month.  Custom Data will either be completely empty, contain one, or contain both.

I am trying to display this data in a table.  Most of it is simple enough apart from the custom data.  At the moment I have something like this

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover additionalMargin alignment reportTable">
    <tr class="col-md-12 noPadding">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Job ID</th>
            <th>Job Name</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Client Name</th>
            <th>Type of work</th>
            <th>Month</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        @if(is_array($jobArray))
            @foreach($jobArray as $array)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $array['jobData']['JobID'] or '' }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $array['jobData']['JobName'] or '' }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $array['jobData']['Category'] or '' }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $array['clientData']['ClientName'] or '' }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $array['customData']['Type of work'] or '' }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $array['customData']['Month'] or '' }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now because the elements in my custom data are also arrays, this means I need to do another loop for them.  So I could potentially do this

```
@if(!empty($array['customData']))
    @foreach($array['customData'] as $data)
        <td>{{ $data['Type of work'] or '' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data['Month'] or '' }}</td>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

The problem with the above is that it seems to create its own tds and things are not matched up properly.  I am essentially seeing something like this
[image]
How can I make things align up appropiately?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You didn't prepare for next row of `$array['customData']` that you have to fill with `<tr>`. Thats why you have all next results in the first column. Here is the solution:

```
@if(is_array($jobArray))
        @foreach($jobArray as $array)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $array['jobData']['JobID'] or '' }}</td>
                <td>{{ $array['jobData']['JobName'] or '' }}</td>
                <td>{{ $array['jobData']['Category'] or '' }}</td>
                @if(!empty($array['customData']))
                    @foreach($array['customData'] as $i => $data)
                        @if($i > 0)
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3"></td>
                        @endif
                            <td>{{ $array['clientData']['ClientName'] or '' }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $data['Type of work'] or '' }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $data['Month'] or '' }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                @else
                        <td colspan="3"></td>
                    </tr>
                @endif
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution to your problem. What you're doing here is checking to see if there is any data in the "customData" object, as the other four objects are constant for all three object types.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover additionalMargin alignment reportTable">
<tr class="col-md-12 noPadding">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Job ID</th>
            <th>Job Name</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Client Name</th>
            <th>Type of work</th>
            <th>Month</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</tr>
<tbody>
    @if(is_array($jobArray))
        @foreach($jobArray as $array)
            @if(!empty($array['customData']))
                @foreach($array['customData'] as $data)
                    <td>{{ isset($array['jobData']['JobID']) ? $array['jobData']['JobID'] : '' }}</td>
                    <td>{{ isset($array['jobData']['JobName']) ? $array['jobData']['JobName'] : '' }}</td>
                    <td>{{ isset($array['jobData']['Category']) ? $array['jobData']['Category'] : '' }}</td>
                    <td>{{ isset($array['clientData']['ClientName']) ? $array['clientData']['ClientName'] : '' }}</td>
                    <td>{{ isset($data['Type of work']) ? $data['Type of work'] : '' }}</td>
                    <td>{{ isset($data['Month']) ? $data['Month'] : '' }}</td>
                @endforeach
            @else 
                <td>{{ isset($array['jobData']['JobID']) ? $array['jobData']['JobID'] : '' }}</td>
                <td>{{ isset($array['jobData']['JobName']) ? $array['jobData']['JobName'] : '' }}</td>
                <td>{{ isset($array['jobData']['Category']) ? $array['jobData']['Category'] : '' }}</td>
                <td>{{ isset($array['clientData']['ClientName']) ? $array['clientData']['ClientName'] : '' }}</td>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @endif
</tbody>
```

If `$array['customData']` **is not** empty, it will populate the same four values for ID, Name, Category, and Client name for EACH unique type of work and/or month. If `$array['customData']` **is** empty, then it will only print the ID, Name, Category and Client Name, then move onto the next Job ID.